# How to use parameters in CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This question is about SQL Server / TSQL.

I use the following technique in Postgres:

```
with i(username, name) as (values (?, ?))
insert into access_log
  (username
  ,name
  ,uid
  )
  values (select i.username
                ,i.name
                ,tab.uid
            from i
            join listofusers tab
              on tab.username  = i.username
          )
```

That is: I create a CTE at the top of my insert/select with the parameters I am passing in. This solves a handful of problems:

1. It allows using the parameter in locations that would otherwise not be allowed.
2. It allows using the same parameter multiple times without specifying it twice on the input.
3. It allows me to rearrange the ? in the select without going to the code to change the order of the parameters being specified.
4. It allows a quick way to look at the list of what is being passed in to get the order correct.

My question is: how can I do this in T-SQL **with a single statement**?

Note that I am not asking for a multiple statement solution. I am only going to accept an answer that can run in a single execute statement in an jdbc/odbc program and does not create temporary tables.

I won't flag answers that are multiple statement solutions because they might be helpful to others.

Comment: What connection technology are you using? ODBC? OLEDB? DBLIB? other?

Answer (score 1):

You can similarly use parameters in a row constructor in T-SQL but you need a `SELECT` within the CTE and `INSERT...SELECT` instead of `INSERT...VALUES`:

```
WITH i AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES (?, ?)) AS i(username, name)
    )
INSERT INTO access_ace_log_restype
  (username
  ,name
  ,uid
    )
    SELECT
         i.username
        ,i.name
        ,tab.uid
    FROM i
    JOIN listofusers tab
        on tab.username  = i.username;
```

Here are examples without the row constructor:

```
WITH i AS (
    SELECT ? AS username, ? AS name
    )
INSERT INTO access_ace_log_restype
  (username
  ,name
  ,uid
    )
    SELECT
         i.username
        ,i.name
        ,tab.uid
    FROM i
    JOIN listofusers tab
        on tab.username  = i.username;

WITH i(username, name) AS (
    SELECT ?, ?
    )
INSERT INTO access_ace_log_restype
  (username
  ,name
  ,uid
    )
    SELECT
         i.username
        ,i.name
        ,tab.uid
    FROM i
    JOIN listofusers tab
        on tab.username  = i.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

In strict T-SQL you must declare a stored procedure to do this as shown here:

```
create procedure InsertUser(@username sysname, @name varchar(255))
as
begin
    insert into access_ace_log_restype
      (username
      ,name
      ,uid
      )
      select tab.username  
            ,@name
            ,tab.uid
      from listofusers tab
      where tab.username  = @username
end;
go
```

However libraries such as ODBC and OLEDB know how to create such a stored procedure on your behalf from SQL that resembles this instead:

```
insert into access_ace_log_restype
  (username
  ,name
  ,uid
  )
  select tab.username  
        ,?
        ,tab.uid
  from listofusers tab
  where tab.username  = ?
```

which closely resembles your original SQL with the parameter order reversed. Extending this with the CTE as in your original post can restore the order if necessary..